# What Are Good Testing Tools For Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, cocos2d-iphone

Are there any testing tools like Frank or KIF that work for cocos2d? What are some ways you guys do automated tests?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Beginning Automated Testing With Xcode](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22590/beginning-automated-testing-with-xcode-part-12) tutorial on Ray's site. He's doing it using Github, Jenkins and TestFlight.